# ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocalización

Al parecer el problema se debe a que Chrome bloquea las consultas de ubicación del usuario que no son seguras, así que he publicado [una pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297595/289691) en Meta SE.

---

En stack snippet estoy probando el código de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Al ejecutarlo, la consola de stack snippet me muestra

> Warning: ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

En mi configuración del navegador he dato permiso para mostrar mi ubicación a es.stackoverflow.com. ¿Qué más me falta?

[image]

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: Probablemente el stack snippet no es considerado un sitio seguro, lo corro locamente y si funciona, también lo subí a un servidor con certificado ssl y también funciona...

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez: Justo estoy investigando en [Stack Snippets Sandbox: Try It Out Here!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) (se me ocurrió luego de publicar la pregunta)

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez no tiene que ver con sitios seguros, sino a que se ejecutan en un sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los stack snippets corren en un [sandbox](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/), por lo que no tienen permiso para obtener la ubicación, y **no hay ninguna opción** que el usuario pueda habilitar para permitirlo.

Específicamente, se debe a que en Stack Overflow no se configura el flag [`allow-same-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe#attr-sandbox). Es decir, que

- lo que en tu publicación está como:

  ```
  <iframe name="833b0476-911f-9afa-831a-c6f045c3a074" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  ```
- debería estar así para que se pueda obtener la ubicación:

  ```
  <iframe name="833b0476-911f-9afa-831a-c6f045c3a074" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <!--                                                         ⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️⬆️                                                                                        -->
  ```

Si se agrega o no, es una discusión compleja para [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com), que ya se consultó en alguna ocasión. Mientras tanto, es así [por diseño](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240215/304899).

---

Alternativas:

1. Publicar el código en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) y agregar el enlace en tu publicación.
2. Pedirle al usuario que ejecute esto en la consola antes de ejecutar el snippet:

   ```
   for (let snippet of document.querySelectorAll('iframe.snippet-box-edit')) { snippet.sandbox.add('allow-same-origin') }
   ```

Comment: Agregué una síntesis como [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297626/289691) en Meta SE así como la conclusión de que se debe realizar un "feature request". En cuanto a la discusión, busqué algo que mencionara específicamente `allow-same-origing` encontré una [solicitud explícita](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/how-is-my-browser-protected-from-xss-in-stack-snippets/240215#comment798731_240215) realizada como comentario el cual no ha tenido respuesta.